# Are middleware and enhancers necessary in redux necessary?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am trying to teach myself redux, I spent a bunch of time learning the outdated documentation. RIP. So now I am learning from https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/quick-start .

When configuring my store to start the tutorial, I came across middleware and enhancers. Can someone explain to me exactly what these do in simple terms and if/when they are necessary!

I appreciate any insight more than you guys know! Thankyou. Also, if you have a good tutorial to follow that would be appreciated as well! Short term I am trying to take a user input and send it for display on a separate page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those docs are for the React-Redux library, specifically, which is the UI bindings layer to let React components talk to the Redux store.  "Middleware" and "enhancers" are a Redux core specific concept, so you won't find any info there.

To actually learn Redux, please read through the newly rewritten official tutorials in the Redux docs, which have been specifically designed to teach you how Redux works and show our recommended practices:

- ["Redux Essentials" tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts): teaches "how to use Redux, the right way", by building a real-world app using Redux Toolkit
- ["Redux Fundamentals" tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-1-overview): teaches "how Redux works, from the bottom up", by showing how to write Redux code by hand and why standard usage patterns exist, and how Redux Toolkit simplifies those patterns

For this question specifically, the ["Store" page in the "Fundamentals" tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-4-store#configuring-the-store) covers what "enhancers" and "middleware" are:

> A store enhancer is like a special version of `createStore` that adds another layer wrapping around the original Redux store. An enhanced store can then change how the store behaves, by supplying its own versions of the store's dispatch, getState, and subscribe functions instead of the originals.

and:

> Enhancers are powerful because they can override or replace any of the store's methods: `dispatch`, `getState`, and `subscribe`.
>
> But, much of the time, we only need to customize how `dispatch` behaves. It would be nice if there was a way to add some customized behavior when dispatch runs.
>
> Redux uses a special kind of addon called middleware to let us customize the `dispatch` function.

Comment: Thank you! This provided so much clarity. I really appreciate it. In order to use redux in react I should follow the regular redux tutorials in order to truly understand what I am doing...correct?

Comment: Yes. The Redux core docs assume you are using Redux and React together, and both the "Essentials" and "Fundamentals" tutorials actually teach how to use React-Redux along with the Redux core. (Frankly, we need to redo the React-Redux tutorial page completely to match our current recommendations.)

Comment: Okay got it! Thank you again. Maybe you should make a tutorial with your own updated version!;)

Comment: Heh. To be clear, I maintain Redux, and I spent most of 2020 writing those two new Redux core docs tutorials :)  I also have [a huge list of other Redux docs updates that need to be done](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/3592). I'm doing this docs work basically myself, so I can only go so fast :)  would love to have folks help me out!